# binary propery in EF4 with mysql -- datatype

Tags: mysql, model, entity-framework-4

I am using mysql together with EF4 and VS2010. I am using model first and uses the **Generate database from model** function to create the database.

Problem is that the binary properties in the model is converted to varbinary(100). I need them to be converted to MEDIUMBLOB.

I know I can change this manually but it would be really great if this could be done automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

Is one-time mapping change automatically enough? ;-)

You can do this in model designer, just select Table mappings from Entity RMB menu, .

**EDIT:**

That is weird, but it looks like actually Table Mappings does not allow to change mapping types.

Anyway, what you can do is to change T4 template to generate SQL. To do this, find file:

```
VS_BASE_DIR\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGenSSDLToSQL10.tt
```

and modify line 165 to return proper SQL Type name instead of the one returned by ToStoreType() extension method of EdmProperty. Unfortunately I didn't find a way to modify it directly.

Of Course this will modify settings for all further projects. If that is not desired, you can make a copy of original template and chose right one through EF Model Properties\DDL Generation Template in every project.

Comment: I can not find any way to set the resulting db field type in the table mappings. Can you explain more please.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up editing the GenerateMySQL.Utility.ttinclude file in the same location.

Comment: Heh, somehow I assumed you use MS SQL ;-) Of course templates depend on DB manufacturer, so you have to adopt solution to your own needs.